# How to fire an event from html dropdown in icCube

Tags: html, events, olap, iccube, iccube-reporting

I have the following code for a dropdown menu that lists month.

```
<select>
 {{ for( var col = 0; col < d.colCount; col++ ) { }}  <!-- This is the way adding js code -->
<option value="[Time].[Month].[month].[{{=d.colLabel(col) }}]">{{=d.colLabel(col) }}</option>
{{ } }}
```

When the user selects an option, an event called month should be fired. How can i do that in icCube OLAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possibilities how you can achieve needed functionality

**On Cell Click Functionality**

There is special attribute that allows to click on specific data cell called **ic3a** [read more...](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/viz/viz/doc/viz24HtmlWidgetFrame.php)

```
<select>
{{ for( var col = 0; col < d.colCount; col++ ) { }}
    <option ic3a="fireClick(0,{{=col}})" value="[Time].[Month].[month].[{{=d.colLabel(col) }}]">
        {{=d.colLabel(col) }}
    </option>
{{ } }}
</select>
```

You should specify event name for "on Cell Click" : "month" in options' "Events" tab.

**External Code**

If you have access to ic3Reporting instance

for example:

```
var ic3Application = ic3.startReport(options);
```

and want to handle current functionality with code on your site you can fire ic3-internal events in such way :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //get ic3application instance

    var ic3Application = ic3.startReport(options);

    function selectMonth (value) {
        ic3Application.fireEvent("month", new viz.event.ValueEvent(value))
    }    
</script>
<select onchange="selectMonth(this.value)">  
    {{ for( var col = 0; col < d.colCount; col++ ) { }}
    <!-- This is the way adding js code -->
    <option value="[Time].[Month].[month].[{{=d.colLabel(col) }}]">
       {{=d.colLabel(col)}}
    </option>
    {{ } }}
</select>
```

**ic3 FILTER Widget**

Suitable when you want to get list of predefined months from cube.
Add MDX Filters > ICCUBE > Drop-down widget and configure it's settings in needed way.

**ic3 ACTION Widget**

This option is suitable when you have specific list of months.

Just create Tools/Utilities > Actions > Drop-down widget and provide needed months at "Items Wizard" options' tab and set "month" as value to "on Selection" event name  at "Events" tab.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please tell me if it is possible to do this within the report itself?

Comment: First, third and forth solutions are suitable for non-embedded iccube-reporting. If I'm missing something could you please clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I tried the following, <select>
{{ for( var col = 0; col < d.colCount; col++ ) { }}
    <option ic3a="fireClick(0,{{=col}})" value="[Time].[Month].[month].[{{=d.colLabel(col) }}]">
        {{=d.colLabel(col) }}
    </option>
{{ } }}
</select>,                     But firing event works only with buttons not with select. Any idea how to make it work with select?